# Groupby across multiple genres of movies in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with the following columns - movieid, movie name, genre 1, genre 2, .... genre n.

There are many movies in the data frame that have multiple genres associated with them. For example: Toy Story is part of Animation, Family, Children, etc.

What I am looking to do is, identify all movies that are part of more than 1 genre.

How do I code for that using Pandas/DataFrame? BTW, I am a complete novice, so please bear with me.

Thanks,
D

Comment: You can do `df.melt(['movieid','movie name'])` which turns all `genre` into a column named `variable`.

Comment: Wouldn't that happen if all genres are in the same column?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a data frame with the following columns - movieid, movie name, genre 1, genre  2, .... genre n.
>
> There are many movies in the data frame that have multiple genres associated with them. For example: Toy Story is part of Animation, Family, Children, etc.
>
> What I am looking to do is, identify all movies that are part of more than 1 genre.

OK so you don't need to groupby anything. I'm going to suggest something a little hacky here, someone might have a prettier version of this code. Just grab the part of your dataframe with columns that are genres (I'm assuming here that there aren't any column names with 'genre' in them that aren't of the type you said.)

```
tempdf = df[[column for column in df if 'genre' in column]]
```

I'll assume for this next bit that the genre columns are coded 0/1. If they aren't you can transform them to that pretty easily.

```
number_of_genres = df.sum(axis=1)
```

Now you only want those movies for which this is >1:

```
df[number_of_genres > 1]
```

Comment: That works like a charm...thanks! I think it is the summing on the column axis that is doing the trick (and of course the greater than 1 condition as well)

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. If there are more complicated manipulations you might need to do here feel free to ask.